# Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: laravel, broadcast

I'am using Laravel 5.8 with pusher to make an broadcast , after i submit the form im getting this **404 not found** i have been searching the google for the answer but no luck.

**PostPublished.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class PostPublished implements ShouldBroadcast {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
      $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn() {
      return new Channel('my-channel');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
      return 'Post-Published';
    }

  }
```

AdminAnnounceController

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([

```
    'department' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'content' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'status' => ['required'],

    ]);

    $data = Announcement::create([

        'department' => $data['department'],
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'content' => $data['content'],
        'status' => $data['status'],

    ]);


     event(new PostPublished($data));




    return redirect('admin_announce')->with('success', 'the Annonucement  has been send');
```

}

Comment: do you use laravel-broadcasting package or laravel-echo?

Comment: yes using  pusher

Comment: you have to start your broadcasting server, is it laravel-echo or laravel-websockets?

Comment: i use laravel-echo

Comment: do you configured your echo server and start ranning `laravel-echo-server start` ?

Comment: no sir  i just watch and follow the tutorial in the youtube "Pusher in laravel"

Comment: read the readme.md file of [laravel-echo repo](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server), everything is described there